# Double loop Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an object like that

```
objs:
    - { key1: value1, key2: [value2, value3] }
    - { key1: value4, key2: [value5, value6] }
```

And I'd like to create the following files

```
value1/value2
value1/value3
value4/value5
value4/value6
```

but I have no idea how to do a double loop using `with_items`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Take a look at `with_subelements` in [Ansible's docs for loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html).

1. You need to create directories:
2. Iterate though `objs` and create files:

Here is an example:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    objs:
      - { key1: value1, key2: [ value2, value3] }
      - { key1: value4, key2: [ value5, value6] }
  tasks:
    - name: create directories
      file: path="{{ item.key1 }}"  state=directory
      with_items:
        objs

    - name: create files
      file: path="{{ item.0.key1 }}/{{ item.1 }}"  state=touch
      with_subelements:
        - objs
        - key2
```

An output is pretty self explanatory, the second loop iterates through the values the way you need it:

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

TASK: [create files] ********************************************************** 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key2': ['value2', 'value3'], 'key1': 'value1'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'key2': ['value5', 'value6'], 'key1': 'value4'})

TASK: [create files] ********************************************************** 
changed: [localhost] => (item=({'key1': 'value1'}, 'value2'))
changed: [localhost] => (item=({'key1': 'value1'}, 'value3'))
changed: [localhost] => (item=({'key1': 'value4'}, 'value5'))
changed: [localhost] => (item=({'key1': 'value4'}, 'value6'))

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Note that since Ansible v2.7, it is preferred to use the [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with) construct with the [`subelements` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#subelements-filter) rather than the `with_X` constructs. See the [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements) documentation on how to migrate.

Comment: When I try this I get an error. I think the first item under `with_subelements` needs `{{ }}`, i.e. `with_subelements: ["{{ objs }}", "key2"]`

Answer (score 21):

In fact you can't. Loops in Ansible are one-dimensional. There is a trick which used to work in previous versions and will again work in Ansible 2.0:

You can have one loop together with an `include` statement and in that included yml you have the 2nd loop. So something along these lines:

**main.yml:**

```
- include: nested_loop.yml obj={{ item }}
  with_items: objs
```

**nested_loop.yml:**

```
- name: create files
  file: path={{obj.key1 }}/{{ item }} state=touch
  with_items: obj.key2
```

Again, this will not work in the current version (1.9.2) of Ansible. The feature was dropped as it caused some problems but will be supported again in Ansible 2.0, so it should be available when you use the [devel branch from github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel).

You can install from github source with this:

```
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
cd ./ansible
source ./hacking/env-setup
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 13):

Adding to udondan's answer (Don't have the rep to comment above):

Using with_items can lead to unexpected results, because the outer loop and the inner loop share a common variable 'item'.

You will want to use 'loop_control' to prevent a variable conflict.

For instance

```
- include: nested_loop.yml obj={{ outside_item }}
  with_items: objs
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outside_item
```

Comment: obj={{ outside_item }} is not even needed here, outside_item can be used directly within nested_loop.yml file.

Comment: I used 'include_tasks' instead of just 'include' to resolve all variables at time of execution

Comment: Here's the documentation for [loop_var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops)